# Why is there a "@firebase/app" npm package when there is "firebase"?

Tags: firebase

Why are there both of these npm packages and they are supposedly even both supposed to be used.
Here someone shows he's including both https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/968

They both point to the same repo? No docs mention @firebase/auth

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/app/v/0.2.0-5

https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase

Answer (score 2):

The package `firebase` contains all firebase services, you can check in the npmjs documentation:

> The full Firebase JavaScript client includes support for Firebase Authentication, the Firebase Realtime Database, Firebase Storage, and Firebase Cloud Messaging.

```
// This import loads the firebase namespace along with all its type information.
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

// These imports load individual services into the firebase namespace.
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';
```

The other package `@firebase/app` doesn't contain all the services if you install it and try to connect to the database it won't work.